# Why is the callback in this method located in a thenable, shouldn't the callback be part of the updateAll method return statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

According to [loopback's official docs](http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#persistedmodel-updateall), the method updateAll takes 3 parameters: where, data, callback, with callback being required.

```
Account.deleteSingleHearingTest = function (req, callback) {
    Account.findById(req.accessToken.userId)
        .then(account => {
            if (!account) {
                throw new Error('Cannot find user');
            }
            return app.models.HearingTest.updateAll({ accountId: account.id, id: req.body.hearingTestId }, { isDeleted: new Date() });

        })
        .then(() => {
            callback(null);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            callback(error);
        });
}
```

I can see that the first two parameters are there, however, the callback doesn't seem to part of the method call.  Shouldn't callback be part of the updateAlll method?

Comment: Maybe their documentation is out of date. Does that code *work*?

Comment: Yes, it works.  I'm trying to write a new remote method and want to make sure I understand how / why it works

Comment: Looking over their documentation, some of their methods support optional callbacks  because they return promises, **If the above code works**, it's a matter of their documentation being out of date. **Keep in mind that if `updateAll` does not return a promise, the `.then` will still (erroneously, in this case) be called.**

Comment: If it works, then note that unless you *need* to use the callback syntax like that, it would probably make a bit more sense to return the thenable so it could be used with `deleteSingleHearingTest(...args).then( ...)`

Comment: You're missing the loopback documentation for using promises instead of callbacks: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-promises.html

Answer (score 0):

I'll elaborate on my comment in an answer. I'll bet your code doesn't actually work, you just think it does.

Let's say that the call to `updateAll` returns something (i.e. does not throw an error) - whether that be null, undefined, true, whatever - then your callback will be called **immediately** and will not actually wait for your `updateAll` to perform it's asynchronous operation. Now, if the call to `updateAll` was sufficiently fast enough, it may **appear** to you that the code worked when it actually didn't.

This might help illustrate what I mean a bit better:

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(function() { return undefined; })
  .then(function() { console.log('it worked!'); });
```

Two things you can do (not dependent on each other):

1. Log the return value of `updateAll` and see if it's a promise
2. Just stick to what the docs say and use a callback.

Personally, I'd do 1 and then I'd do 2 :)